# String.padStart() not applying in Angular function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular function which receives a number from a GET request and then will encode that number as base 64. I am trying to use the padStart function outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), but when I log the string after calling the function, the string is not padded. Any ideas why?

Angular:

```
$scope.generateCode = function(){
    var number = autogenNumber(); //Pull the number
    number.then(function (result) { //Then increment up and convert
        var working_str = result.toString();
        console.log("The pre padded string is", working_str);
        working_str.padStart(8, '1234');
        console.log("The padded string is now", working_str, typeof working_str);
    })

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is immutable. You have to reassign

```
working_str = working_str.padStart(8, '1234');
```

Comment: Thanks! I really should've seen that.